# How to view PDF in a gallery view

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, web

Is it possible to view the PDF as a gallery view on a website. My client wants to dump all of his pdf on a directory and wants other people to access all of them through website. I know we can have a gallery view for the image file but I wants to know if that is possible with the pdf file as well. He would also wants that website accessible through touch screen device.
any information would be really appreciable.

Thanks a lot

Comment: do u tried anything? if u tried put it in js fiddle it will be easy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this code is used to view the pdf. check it. May be it will help.

```
             <!--[if IE]>
                <object type="application/pdf" width="718" height="700">
                  <param name="src" value="219.pdf" >
                  <param name="controller" value="true" >
                </object>
                <![endif]-->

                <!--[if !IE]> <!-->
                <object data="219.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="718" height="700">
                  alt : <a href="219.pdf">test.pdf</a>
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I think I want to display the album of all pdf in a specific directory, say all pdf stored in /pdf/  and there name is 1.pdf,2.pdf etc. I want to flip through all pdf in that directory.

Comment: you need to display all the pdf in one page?iterate this code in foreach condition by changing the file name.